# Array & segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I'm creating the below array:

```
int p[100];
int
main ()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        p[i] = 148;
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

The program aborts with a segmentation fault after writing 1000 positions of the array, instead of the 100. I know that C doesn't check if the program writes out of bounds, this is left to the OS. I'm running it on ubuntu, the size of the stack is 8MB (limit -s). Why is it aborting after 1000? How can I check how much memory my OS allocates for an array?
Sorry if it's been asked before, I've been googling this but can't seem to find a specific explanation for this.

Comment: It's just UB, Don't try to reason about it.

Comment: The parenthesis in the return statement are redundant, much like if you used them in the assignment ... `p[i] = (148);`

Comment: It means that at the exact location where the problem occurs there is an invalid memory access, so not necessarily at 1000, but it's 1000 in your case, could be 981 or 123 anything.

Comment: It is like asking: _"If I run around on the highway, why am I not immediately hit by a car? I managed to run around for 10 minutes before one finally hit me."_  It is not meaningful to analyse why. Maybe there wasn't a lot of traffic that day. Maybe you were wearing colorful clothes. Maybe you were running fast. Who cares? It is not useful knowledge. Simply don't run around on the highway and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appear that you clearly get **over** the 100 elements defined (`int p[100];`) since you make a loop **without** any limitation (`while (1)`).

I would suggest to you to use a `for` loop instead:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  // do your stuff...
}
```

Regarding you more specific question about the memory, consider that any outside range request (in your situation over the 100 elements of the array) can produce an error. The fact that you notice it was 1000 in your situation can change depending on memory usage by other program.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies, my question is, since I get the segmentation fault consistently after 1000, is there any way I can check what are my SO allocates when I create the array? Or is it going to depend on many factors (other programs running, etc...).

Comment: Sorry to insist but you misused the term _consistently_ since you may have different behavior at any time! The memory allocated by your instruction `int p[100]` is `sizeof(int)*100` (in bytes)

Answer (score 1):

Accessing an invalid memory location leads to [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which means that anything can happen. It is not necessary for a segmentation-fault to occur.

Answer (score 1):

*...the size of the stack is 8MB (limit -s)...*

variable `int p[100];` is not at the stack but in *data area* because it is defined as global. It is not initialized so it is placed into BSS area and filled with zeros. You can check that printing array values just at the beginning of `main()` function.

As other said, using `p[i] = 148;` you produced undefined behaviour. Filling 1000 position you most probably reached end of BSS area and got segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

It will fail once the CPU says

> HEY! that's not Your memory, leave it!

The fact that the memory is not inside of the array does not mean that it's not for the application to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

> The program aborts with a segmentation fault after writing 1000 positions of the array, instead of the 100.

You do not reason out Undefined Behavior. Its like asking  `If 1000 people are under a coconut tree, will 700 hundred of them always fall unconscious if a Coconut smacks each of their heads?`